# Neato XV11 firmware version to run neato_robot?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I need to know please, the correct Naeto XV11 firmware version to run this ROS driver, http://wiki.ros.org/neato_robot?distro=fuerte

I allready try im my Naeto XV11, but it doesn't work. After analyze the problem i notice for example in "xv11_motor_info" expected messages, i only receive 15 values, instead the 30 values expected in the driver code.

**getmotors response:**
Parameter,Value
Brush_RPM,0
Brush_mA,0
Vacuum_RPM,0
Vacuum_mA,0
LeftWheel_RPM,0
LeftWheel_Load%,0
LeftWheel_PositionInMM,0
LeftWheel_Speed,0
RightWheel_RPM,0
RightWheel_Load%,0
RightWheel_PositionInMM,0
RightWheel_Speed,0
Charger_mAH, 0
SideBrush_mA,0

**Naeto Information:**
**SW** 3.2.18755
**LDS** V2.6.15295
**Board** Rev 64
**Board SW** 18077

I need to downgrade or upgrade the Naeto Firmware?

Best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98096/neato-xv11-firmware-version-to-run-neato_robot?/) by [Andre Araujo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1209/andre-araujo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might try looking at this fork: https://github.com/vegelius/neato_robot as the author says they have updated to the 3.1FW, I unfortunately do not have access to a newer Neato at this time.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-11-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0